# Разница между Morbo и Hypnotoad в Mojolicious

Tags: perl, mojolicious

объясните мне пожалуйста разницу между Morbo и Hypnotoad в Mojolicious. Чем они отличаются?

Comment: морбо заточен под разработку, гипножаба для продакшена

Answer (score 0):

Morbo сделан на `Mojo::Server::Daemon`, а Hypnotoad — на `Mojo::Server::Prefork`. Собственно, в префорке (`Mojo::Server::Prefork` тоже сделан на `Mojo::Server::Daemon`) основная разница, которая делает Hypnotoad более эффективным в продакшене.

Comment: так в чем разница-то? в чем эффективность? пожалуйста, напишите об этом в ответе

Comment: В чём эффективность модели префорка можно прочесть, например, тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/25894770/1186729